# React-Redux access props inside a nested object within component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a react-redux application and I am able to receive props inside a component.

This is my `componentDidMount()` function

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.graphdata = {

            dnsCountPlot: {
                data: [{
                    type: 'scatter',  
                    x: this.props.dnsCountPlot.x,
                    y: this.props.dnsCountPlot.y,
                    fill: 'tozeroy',
                    marker: {
                        color: 'rgb(99, 128, 185)'
                    }
                }],
                layout: {
                    title: '',
                    xaxis: {
                        title: 'time'
                    },
                    autosize: true

                },
                config: {
                    showLink: false,
                    displayModeBar: true
                }
            }

        };
}
```

The `this.props.dnsCountPlot.x` variable is updated every 10 sec and when I print the variable it shows that.

However the `this.graphdata` variable which contains the `this.props.dnsCountPlot.x` variable is not being updated. Any idea if this is possible and how to do it?

```
   componentDidUpdate() {

        console.log(this.props.dnsCountPlot.x); //Successfully Updated
        console.log(this.graphdata);            // Doesnt reflect changes of this.props.dnsCountPlot.x   

    }
```

the index.js file

```
const initialState = {
    dnsCountPlot : {
        x: [],
        y: []
    }
};
const store = createStore(reducers(initialState));

const history = createBrowserHistory();

startSocket(store);

ReactDOM.render((
    <Provider store={store}>
        <HashRouter history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" name="Home" component={Full}/>
            </Switch>
        </HashRouter>
    </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should use `componentWillReceiveProps` to get the new props. Take a look at [component lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)

Comment: you're missing a 'data' array with a 0th element for the `x,y` in your initial state in your redux store as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set your initial state to have those props, then use the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method to update the state with `this.setState( {...} )` which will redraw the component. Example:

```
constructor( props ){
    super();
    this.state = { ...props };
}
componentWillReceiveProps( nextProps ){
    this.setState( { ...nextProps } );
}
render(){
   <span>this.state.dnsCountPlot.x</span>
}
```

Or if you want:

```
constructor( props ){
    super();
    this.state = {
       graphData: {
         dnsCountPlot: {
            data: [{
                type: 'scatter',  
                x: this.props.dnsCountPlot.x,
                y: this.props.dnsCountPlot.y,
                fill: 'tozeroy',
                marker: {
                    color: 'rgb(99, 128, 185)'
                }
            }],
            layout: {
                title: '',
                xaxis: {
                    title: 'time'
                },
                autosize: true

            },
            config: {
                showLink: false,
                displayModeBar: true
            }
        }
      }
    };
}
componentWillReceiveProps( nextProps ){
    this.setState( { graphData: {
      ...this.state.graphData
      dnsCountPlot:{
        ...this.state.graphData.dnsCountPlot,
        data:[{
          ...this.state.graphData.dnsCountPlot.data[ 0 ],
          x: nextProps.dnsCountPlot.x,
          y: nextProps.dnsCountPlot.y,
        }] } } } );
}
render(){
   <span>this.state.graphData.dnsCountPlot.data[ 0 ].x</span>
}
```

---UPDATE---

It has been argued that setting the state with the props initially is an anti-pattern to React. And it even says so in the docs... HOWEVER, this stops being true if you complete this anti-pattern with an acceptable pattern of updating the state when those properties are updated on the component as done here in the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method.

Comment: I am using redux, so there isn't a state but a store

Comment: React components always have a state. Don't down vote until you're sure my dude.

Comment: You hook the component to the store with connect, and it effects the props. True. But also the components all have a state and the component relies on to update it's view properly. Do a little more digging you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: You can also use `this.state` in any of the lifecycle or `this` methods

Comment: This works, I was under the assumption that the store replaces the state entirely. Thanks for the detailed answer..

Comment: It can, but since redux and react do their best to be less opinionated you have to make the connections you want so you can do your best to prioritize when you want a component to redraw because it can get heavy.